# Identity relating $V \circ \nabla F$ and $V( \nabla \circ F)$?

Tags: calculus, vectors, proof-explanation, vector-analysis, tensors

I’ve been trying to derive the Leibniz Integral Rule [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) in 3D and I’ve nearly got it, but where Wikipedia shows $V \circ \nabla F$, my approach gives $V( \nabla \circ F)$. I’m thinking that the two quantities are related, but I have failed to show how. My approach has been brute force in Cartesian coordinates.

If you have another approach for figuring out the identity, I would be super grateful. V and F are both vectors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you want compare a vector and a scalar. They could not appear in the same equation.

Comment: V is a vector, grad F is a rank 2 tensor, so the first term is a vector. Of course, so is second term.